# I want empno,ename,job,ASSIGNED_MANAGER(manager Name not Number ) can any one help me out code

Tags: sql, oracle

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB         ASSIGNED_MANAGER
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   -----
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782
```

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

That's self outer join:

- *self* so that you'd use the same (`emp`) table twice: once to fetch employees, and another time to fetch managers' names
- *outer*, because there are employees who don't have managers

---

```
SQL> select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, m.ename
  2  from emp e left join emp m on e.mgr = m.empno;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB       ENAME
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7902 FORD       ANALYST   JONES
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   JONES
      7900 JAMES      CLERK     BLAKE
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  BLAKE
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  BLAKE
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN  BLAKE
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  BLAKE
      7934 MILLER     CLERK     CLARK
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK     SCOTT
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER   KING
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   KING
      7566 JONES      MANAGER   KING
      7369 SMITH      CLERK     FORD
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```